# Adding the sum of the entered numbers when you enter 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, sum, addition, do-while

I am absolutely new to C# and I am at total lost. What I need to do is enter numbers as many as possible and keep entering but when you enter the value "0" that is when you add all the entered numbers all up.

This is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Activity2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n, sum, x = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            while (n != 0);

            {

                sum = n + x;
                x = n;
                n = sum;
                Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + n);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You might consider adding them as you go and just printing the total when '0' is entered.

Answer (score 2):

Some advices:

- The `while` loop is a better practice than the `do..while` loop.
- You should use the `int.TryParse` method for input validation.
- You should calculate sum of numbers inside loop.
- You can solve the problem with only two int variables: `n` for readed numbers and `sum` for numbers sum.

For example, you can solve your problem with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
        {
            if (n == 0) 
                break;
            sum += n;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Well this is correct but a better handling of the user input should be suggested here. (Int32.TryParse). By the wa you should really add explanations and not just code.

Comment: @Steve, I added check with TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do that with do ... while ... loop.

```
private static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        sum += n;
    } while (n != 0);
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is:"+sum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

ConvertToInt32() is a method for converting a string to int32 (int).

Answer (score -1):

You print the sum outside while loop.

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Activity2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n, sum, x = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            while (n != 0);
            {

                sum = n + x;
                x = n;
                n = sum;


            }
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + n);
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }

}
```